# Sorting an array by the children attribute in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my app, I have a map of an array that returns a div with a data-date attribute like so:

```
Note I cannot sort the array here as I don't have any dates to compare them with, only the ID of the element


const mappedArray = array.map(el=>{
  return (
   <DivComponent el={el} />
  )
})
```

Inside the DivComponent, I make a fetch to firebase where I get the info of each div along with a timestamp

```
const DivComponent = (props) => {
 const info = useGetInfo(props.el.id) 
 return (
  <div data-data={info.date.toDate()}>Some content</div>
 )
}
```

Given these conditions, is it possible to sort the array above given that each children have an assigned date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it okay to change the props on DivComponent and move the useGetInfo outside?

```
const mappedArray = array.map(el=>useGetInfo(el.id))
.sort((info1,info2)=>info1.date.toDate()>info2.date.toDate()?1:-1)
.map(info=>{
 return (
    <DivComponent info={info} />
  )
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).